# How can I create a field for code entering with automatic advancing in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, input

Title might be confusing so: I want to create an input for a 6-Digit code with automatic advancing like apple has on its website for 2FA. So you have 6 Input boxes, click in one enter a number and it automatically advances into the next field, the last field presses the enter button. I am using Swift 3.

Comment: Use the **textFieldHasChanged** method to the first 5 textfields and there add **nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UITextFieldDelegate methods with a set of 6 UITextField controls

Use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to see that a character has been entered, and move firstResponder to the next field, and finally to the `UIButton`

Alternatively, you could use a `UIPickerView` with 6 wheels, or 6 `UIPickerViews` with a single section, and move on to the next when a value is selected

Comment: Thanks will give that a try, sounds promising